# ipython notebook running in cron with a self-signed certificate

Tags: ssl, cron, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run ipython notebook as a cronjob but ipython throws a warning that must be acknowledged when starting with a self signed certificate created with this process http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/public_server.html.

Is there any way to force use of a self signed certificate without a warning and a prompt when ipython notebook is starting?  Ipython notebook asks if to proceed with self-signed certificate in the startup process.

I am starting ipython with:

```
ipython notebook --profile=notebook_server
```

Comment: Why do you use https if you want to ignore the protections offered by https by using a self-signed certificate and ignoring the warnings?

Comment: well, it  is several fold but essentially we have internal desktops and servers but do not manage the network  that connects them  We want to communicate with encryption to the two on ipython.

Comment: But without proper checking who you are talking to your encryption is not safe, because it is open to a man-in-the-middle attack. You might still use self-signed certificates, but then you have to verify that the certificate is the expected one. Usually this is done by importing the certificate into your list of trusted CA.

Comment: Oh absolutely, I have imported the certificates in firefox for the users.   My issue is literally, ipython notebook loads and says "Proceed with a self-signed certificate y/n?"

Comment: The version I use does not ask this. Can you please add *to your question* the version you use and the exact command line you are using to start the notebook and which warning you get there?

Comment: I am using 3.0.0.  ipython notebook --profile=nbserver

Comment: I think it it is trying to start some (command-line) browser which then shows this message. But it would be really helpful if you would add more information **to the question** and not inside the comments. Best you insert the full output from the startup, i.e. including the **full** command line and **all** output.